# Error undefined method download de Maatwebsite 3.1 Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel, maatwebsite

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\AsistenciaDocente;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Exports\AsistenciaDiariaDocentes;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

public function export()
{
  return Excel::download(new AsistenciaDiariaDocentes(), 'asistencias.xlsx');
}
```

**Export**

```
namespace App\Exports;
use App\Models\AsistenciaDocente\AsistenciaDocenteModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
{
class AsistenciaDiariaDocentes implements FromCollection
{
public function collection()
{
return AsistenciaDocenteModel::asistenciaDiariaDocentes();
}
```

> **Model**

```
namespace App\Models\AsistenciaDocente;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class AsistenciaDocenteModel extends Model
{
public static function asistenciaDiariaDocentes(){
return DB::connection('asistencia_docentes')->select('call sp_asistenciaDiariaDocentes()');
}
```

> **Problema**

```
Call to undefined method Pecee\Http\Response::download()
```

¿Saben porque me sale este error?

Cree un proyecto solo para probar la libraria y si me funciona pero en el proyecto que estoy trabajando me sale este error.

Comment: Eso no tiene que ver con el paquete laravel-excel, ni siquiera laravel. Tenés otro paquete ahí que está interfiriendo con las responses de laravel.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ tienes un consejo para saber cual puede ser?

Comment: Supongo que este https://github.com/skipperbent/simple-php-router por el mensaje de error. Mira en composer.json si figura ahí.

Comment: No lo veo, solo tengo :     "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.1",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0",
        "laraveles/spanish": "^1.4",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "~2"
    },

Comment: No sé por qué aparecería un error de ese paquete entonces. Antes de probar algo más drástico, prueba correr este comando `composer dump-autoload`, a ver si quedó cargado de otra instalación.

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error, pero es seguro que el error se deba a un problema con las librerias?

Comment: al ejecutar "composer dump-autoload" me salio esto : does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201, tendrá algo que ver? si optimizo las librerias.

Comment: "does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard" es porque tu proyecto no cumple los stanrdares psr-4. ¿Y te sigue dando el mismo error al descargar el excel? No estoy seguro de que sea un error de las librerías, nunca había visto eso en laravel, solo googleé el mensaje de error y me apareció que esa clase `Pecee\Http\Response` es de ese paquete.